# Why don't my collapsible Bootstrap table rows have a transition?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table of data that I want to expand each row to show more info. I'm using the **Collapse** component. Clicking a button in each row will show the collapsed row underneath it. This seems to work fine, but I don't get the slow transition that the bootstrap documentation shows. I suppose it's because the documentation is not doing this as part of a table. Is this possible when collapsing, and showing a table row?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Collapse Test</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
                            V
                        </button> ID 1
          </td>
          <td>Dog</td>
          <td>Cat</td>
          <td>Fish</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
          <td colspan="4">
            <p>Here's some content that will be hidden until you expand ID1.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus quisquam est quia ducimus quos alias distinctio illum voluptates sunt facere. Perferendis in vero optio? Laudantium, non debitis ratione fuga perspiciatis nihil quasi possimus,
              dolorem tempore illo at molestias aspernatur hic autem! Perspiciatis culpa voluptatum totam deleniti qui aliquam, tempore nisi sequi et.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
                            V
                        </button> ID 2
          </td>
          <td>Apple</td>
          <td>Banana</td>
          <td>Orange</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
          <td colspan="4">
            <p>Here's some content that will be hidden until you expand ID2.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus quisquam est quia ducimus quos alias distinctio illum voluptates sunt facere. Perferendis in vero optio? Laudantium, non debitis ratione fuga perspiciatis nihil quasi possimus,
              dolorem tempore illo at molestias aspernatur hic autem! Perspiciatis culpa voluptatum totam deleniti qui aliquam, tempore nisi sequi et.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Rx+T1VzGupg4BHQYs2gCW9It+akI2MM/mndMCy36UVfodzcJcF0GGLxZIzObiEfa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. You were allowed to post that as it is only because you marked your table row as code. That's not adequate. Also tag your Bootstrap version.